# issue with Alt Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help in a jquery code. I have developed a website where the header image will change when we hover on the navigation tabs like Home, About Us, etc. The problem is I have included the images that need to changed on hover in "alt" attribute. This works fine with chrome but not in firefox and IE. The link for the website is

```
            http://datacrawl.in/home.html
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="home.html"> Home  </a><span style = "color: #FFF; position: relative;  left: 23px; "> | </span></li>
<li><a class = "ser" alt = "images/7.jpg" href="about.html"> About Us</a><span style = "color: #FFF; position:             relative; left: 23px;"> | </span></li>
<li><a class = "ser" alt = "images/5.jpg" href=""> Services </a> <span style = "color: #FFF; position: relative; left:     23px;"> | </span>
<ul>
<li style = "background-color: #8e64b0;"><a class = "ser" alt =  "images/3.jpg" href="software.html"> Software             Development </a></li>
<li style = "background-color: #7b55a0;"><a class = "ser" alt = "images/2.jpg" href="web.html"> Web & Graphic              Designing </a></li>
<li style = "background-color: #8e64b0;"><a class = "ser" alt = "images/4.jpg" href="technical.html"> Technical            Training </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a class = "ser" alt = "images/6.jpg" href=""> Portfolio  </a><span style = "color: #FFF; position: relative;          left: 23px;"> | </span>
</ul>
```

The jquery code I have used to do this is given below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.heading1, .heading2, .ser').mouseover(function () {
        var src = $(this).attr('alt');
        $('.header img').stop().fadeOut(50, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', src);
            $(this).fadeIn(50);
        });
    });
    $('.heading1, .heading2, .ser').mouseout(function () {
        $('.header img').stop().fadeOut(50, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/1.jpg');
            $(this).fadeIn(50);
        });
    });
});
```

So when ever I mouse over the links with classes heading1, heading2 and ser It will change the header image to respective alt attribute image that is set by me. This is not working in firefox and IE. Please help me with this. Thank You.

Comment: As a first step, try formatting your JavaScript code readably. http://jsbeautifier.org and similar can help. I've done it for you on this occasion.

Comment: Please remove all whitespaces around "=" and other attributes and try again.

Comment: Your html is horrible, start improving the code first, by removing the whitespaces; they could cause the issues.

Comment: Hey, it's working fine in FF but you need to give some time to load the image.. just mouseover the menu and wait for some time, don't mouseout immediately..

Comment: The third and the last `<li>` is missing a closing tag (`</li>`). This might cause some problems in IE

Comment: Thats true, after waiting about 4 seconds, everything is loading. But please fix all the errors http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://datacrawl.in/home.html returns.

Comment: sorry that I dint edit the HTML code before posting..I am sure I have neglected the unwanted space....and Sudip you are right and is there any solution to overcome the delaying process of image loading?

Comment: Yes, load the images separately. Because when you have the url in the alt attribute, they will only be fetched when you hover over the links. If you have them in the DOM, they will load at the same time as the rest of your page.

Answer (score 1):

Good God no! Don't use `alt` to store data. Use the `data` attribute instead. It's what it's designed for.

Also, it probably isn't working because you have placed `alt` onto an anchor tag. `alt` is only used for `img` tags.

**HTML Reworked:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a><span style = "color: #FFF; position: relative;  left: 23px; "> | </span></li>
    <li><a class = "ser" data-image = "images/7.jpg" href="about.html"> About Us</a><span style = "color: #FFF; position: relative; left: 23px;"> | </span></li>
    <li><a class = "ser" data-image = "images/5.jpg" href=""> Services </a> <span style = "color: #FFF; position: relative; left: 23px;"> | </span>
        <ul>
            <li style = "background-color: #8e64b0;"><a class = "ser" data-image =  "images/3.jpg" href="software.html"> Software Development </a></li>
            <li style = "background-color: #7b55a0;"><a class = "ser" data-image = "images/2.jpg" href="web.html"> Web & Graphic Designing </a></li>
            <li style = "background-color: #8e64b0;"><a class = "ser" data-image = "images/4.jpg" href="technical.html"> Technical Training </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class = "ser" data-image = "images/6.jpg" href=""> Portfolio  </a><span style = "color: #FFF; position: relative; left: 23px;"> | </span>
</ul>
```

**jQuery Reworked:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.ser').mouseover(function () {
        var src = $(this).data('image');
        $('.header img').stop().fadeOut(50, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', src);
            $(this).fadeIn(50);
        });
    });
    $('a.ser').mouseout(function () {
        $('.header img').stop().fadeOut(50, function () {
            $(this).attr('src', 'images/1.jpg');
            $(this).fadeIn(50);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did it work? If so, please consider marking this as the answer to help others with similar issues in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oh god please don't misuse alt tags for this kind of purpose. You can use data attributes for this kind of thing:

```
<li><a class="ser" data-header-image="images/3.jpg" href="my-page.html">Link Text</a></li>
```

Your javascript can stay pretty much the same, but look at that data attribute instead. Alt attributes hold a semantic implication, so really shouldn't be misused. Your code as it stands would be confusing as hell to anyone with a screen reader.

I also second others' sentiments about making sure that your spacing etc is right and your closing tags are there... That can cause problems, too

Answer (score -1):

changing img source isn't a good idea for me, try making a background sprite and moving it by adding class to the header